# Jquery Collapsing with Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a dual-collapsing view that, upon a button click, will make an image 'collapse' away and a text section 'collapse' open. This functionality is work. However, when I add an `onclick()` to the button to change the color (via classes) and font-awesome picture, there is weird functionality. Generally it works, however usually the first click upon reloading the page ONLY causes the button to change, no collapsing. What gives!?

Here is some code, comment for anything else that may be needed:

Haml button and subsequent collapsing sections:

```
%h2
  Name
  %button.btn.btn-info.pull-right{data:{toggle:"collapse", target:".buy-collapse#{ammo.id}", parent:"accordion"}, onclick:'buyChange($(this))'}
      %i.fa.fa-shopping-cart
        Buy
%hr
// Order Form
.collapse{class:"buy-collapse#{ammo.id}"}
  -# Form is here

= image_tag "ammos/"+ammo.img, :class=>"", :class=>"img-responsive img-centered buy-collapse#{ammo.id} collapse in", :alt=>''
```

Internal javascript function for the button change:

```
:javascript
  function buyChange($this) {
    if ($this.hasClass("btn-info")) {
      $this.removeClass("btn-info");
      $this.addClass("btn-danger");
      $this.html('<i class="fa fa-times"> Cancel</i>');
    } else {
      $this.removeClass("btn-danger");
      $this.addClass("btn-info");
      $this.html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"> Buy</i>');
    }
  }
```

Some info about my project, rails -v 4.1, bootstrap, font-awesome

Answer (score 0):

Is your document loaded? Generally, you don't want mix your html and javascript like you have here. Try adding something like the code below to the appropriate javascript file in your `app/assets/javascripts` folder instead:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  // I'd recommend an id selector here
  $('button.btn.btn-info.pull-right').on('click', function() {
    // Add your code to change button and collapse form and
    // whatever else you want to happen on click here.
  });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```